# In two days' time = within two days?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

What is the difference between:

> The package will be delivered **in two days' time.**

And

> The package will be delivered **within two days.**

Are they the same or different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If today is Monday, and a company tells me:

> Your package will arrive **in two days' time**.

then I will expect the package to arrive on Wednesday.

However, if today is Monday, and a company tells me:

> Your package will arrive **within two days**.

then I will expect the package to arrive on Tuesday **or** Wednesday.

If we change the verbiage from **two** to **four** then:

- *in four days' time* means the package is expected to arrive on Friday
- *within four days* means the package will arrive no later than Friday – but it could arrive on Thursday or perhaps even on Wednesday.

---

In other words, "in two days' time" is typically a **prediction**, while "within two days" specifies an **upper limit**.

Comment: So it's **''in two days''=''in two days' time''** right? But why did they put **''time''** in that?

Comment: I guess it's colloquial

Answer (score 1):

in two days time = when the delivery will occur

within two days = implies there is a limit. No later than two days.

**You must do this task in two days**. [usually, two days from some date or you have two days to do it.]

You must do this task within two days. [we don't know when those days will be and it sets a time limit on how long you can take.]

within two days = within 48 hours. [sets a limit]

in two days = in 48 hours. [says when or describes how many days are needed]

Comment: I think it's 48 hours for 2 days.