# in has two meanings - after, within? How to understand which one is meant?

Tags: prepositions

Dictionaries say this:
in (prep)
1 before or when (a period of time) has elapsed: come back in one year.

2 This word is used before a noun that refers to a period of time, to show that something happens during that time, or occurs within a period or limit of that time: We did the task in only ten minutes. We will be there in an hour.

So, "Come in ten minutes" may mean "Come within the next ten minutes" or "Come after the next ten minutes is over". How can it be sorted out?

Comment: It means the second -- be here when ten minutes have elapsed., that is, ten minutes from the time the words were said. That is why the speaker specified "ten minutes" instead of five or three or whatever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time Expressions with "in"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208621/time-expressions-with-in). Also [In two days' time = within two days?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/173514/in-two-days-time-within-two-days)